# Make find command case insensitive

Tags: linux, unix

How would I alter the following command:

```
find FOLDER -type f -regex ".*\.\(xls\|xlsx\|avi\|mov\|mp4\|mpg\|mpeg\|ts\|wav\|cap\|cc\|itt\|scc\|srt\|jpeg\|jpg\|png\|tif\|tiff\)
```

To enable the finding of case-insensitive extensions, such as "file.mpg" and "file.MPG" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use case-insensitive predicates (`-ilname`, `-iname`, `-ipath`, `-iregex`, `-iwholename`).